A multidimensional Central Limit Theorem for Pólya Urns
I know that if we fix $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d\ge1$ and $S\ge1$ integers, and we define the $d$-dimensional process $(Z(n))_{n\ge0}$ as
follows: let $V$ be a Dirichlet random variable of parameter $\big(\frac{\alpha_1}S,\dots,\frac{\alpha_d}S\big)$ and let $(X_m)_{m\ge1}$ be a
sequence of random variables such that, for all $k\ge1$, for all $1\le i \le d$, $\mathbb{P}(X_k=e_i|V)=V_i$. Let $Z_i(0)=\alpha_i\ge1$ for all $1\le i\le d$ and, for all $n\ge1$, $Z(n)=Z(0)+S\sum^n_{k=1}X_k$. Then, $(Z(n))_{n\ge0}$ is a Pólya urn of initial composition $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d)$ and replacement matrix $S\cdot$ Id.
To understand the difference between $Z(n)$ and $Z_i(n)$, we have, for the canonical base in $\mathbb{R}^d$: $Z(n)=\sum^d_{i=1}Z_i(n)e_i$, or in words, for a $d$-colour Pólya urn $U(n)$, $U_i(n)$ denotes the number of balls of colour $i$ at time $n$.
Using this information, and with the help of the multidimensional CLT I want to prove the following:

Theorem. Assume that $(U(n))_{n\ge0}$ is a Pólya urn of initial composition
$(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d)$ and replacement matrix $R=S\cdot Id$ for some $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d$, $S\ge1$. Then, in distribution as $n\uparrow\infty$,$$\frac{U(n)-nSV}{S\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma^2)$$ where $\Sigma^2=\sum^d_{i=1}V_ie_i^te_i-V^tV$.

To find this, we take advantage of the fact that, in distribution, $U(n)=Z(n)$ $\forall n$
Conditionally on $V$, we have: $\mathbb{E}[X|V]=e_i\cdot V_i \ (\forall1\le i\le d)=V$
Now, we want to apply the multidimensional CLT to $Z(n)$, since it is defined by a summation of a constant $(Z(0))$ and a sum of random vectors. The $X_i$ are i.i.d. (identically distributed is clear by definiton and for independence note that $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]=\mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{E}[X_j]$ for any pair $1\le i,j\le n$, $i\not=j$ using Law of total expectation).
So can we apply the CLT to $Z(n)$ or do we better apply it to $Z(n)-Z(0)$? Either way, by the CLT, conditionally on $V$ we get $$\frac{SX_1+\dots+SX_n-n\mathbb{E}[SX|V]}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{Z(n)-Z(0)-nSV}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma^2)$$ where $\Sigma^2=\text{Cov}(X|V)=\sum^d_{i=1}V_ie_i^te_i-V^tV$, where $X$ is a copy of $X_1$.
Does this makes sense? Where does the $S^{-1}$ factor in the Theorem comes from?
Reference: PÒLYA URNS AND OTHER REINFORCEMENT PROCESSES

The reason your last two questions are so poorly received may be that to understand them, the reader would have to read another text and then go through your long list of questions and doubts. It is better to edit the question in such a way that the reader has the required definitions and results together with some illustrative examples on how to use the notation, and at the end only one or two specific questions are stated. I tried to make your question more visible by adding the tags "probability" and "statistics".

@Amir Thank you for your observation. If this question does not get a relevant answer or comment to the topic, I will post another question, maybe just stating the theorem and trying to prove it as I did, so it will be indeed shorter. I will also add my main reference at the end as "optional" to see.

You may improve this question today, because there are still 5 days left until the end of the bounty period. Just clearly introduce the notation along with illustrative examples to help readers understand the stochastic experiment and the notation you used, and then state the main claim you want to prove. At the end, add your own efforts or references if anyone needs to read them.

Notation: Fix $S \geq 1$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^d_+$. Define the process
$\{U_t\}_{t \geq 0} \subset \mathbb{R}^d_+$ by
$$
U_{t+1} = U_{t} + S e_{X_{t+1}}, \quad \mbox{for}~t=0, 1, 2, \ldots.
$$
Above, we have $X_{t} | V \stackrel{\rm iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Categorical}(V)$ for all $t \geq 1$ and $V \sim \mathsf{Dirichlet}(\alpha)$.

Applying the CLT: Define $Y_t = U_t - U_0$,
$$
Y_t = S \sum_{\tau = 1}^t e_{X_{\tau}}, \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\mathbb{E}[Y_t \mid V] = t S V. 
$$
For any $t \geq 1$, and integers $1 \leq i,j\leq d$, $\mathrm{Cov}(e_{X_t} \mid V)_{ij} = \delta_{ij} V_i- V_i V_j$.
Consequently,
$$
\Sigma \equiv \mathrm{Cov}(e_{X_t} \mid V) = \sum_{i=1}^d V_i (e_i \otimes e_i) - V \otimes V.
$$
Now we can apply the CLT conditionally. Define
$$
W_t = \frac{Y_t - \mathbb{E}[Y_t \mid V]}{S\sqrt{t}} \equiv 
\frac{U_t - tSV}{S\sqrt{t}}, \quad t \geq 1.
$$
Since $X_t$ are conditionally iid, the CLT yields
conditionally $W_t \to \mathsf{N}(0, \Sigma)$ in distribution as $t \to \infty.$
Formally, this means for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$,
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(W_t \leq u \mid V)
\to \mathbb{P}(W_V \leq u \mid V)
\quad \mbox{where} \quad W_V \sim \mathsf{N}\big(0, \Sigma(V)\big). 
$$
(Above $w \leq u $ means $w_i \leq u_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, d$.)
Note that this also implies (e.g., by dominated convergence)
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} 
\mathbb{P}(W_t \leq u) = 
\mathbb{E}_V[\mathbb{P}(W_V \leq u)].
$$

Sorry if I am still back, even after accepting your answer, but, since the comments were deleted, it still does not make sense the fact that $U_0$ vanishes.
On one hand we have $Y_t-\mathbb{E}[Y_t]=U_t-U_0-\mathbb{E}[U_t]+U_0=U_t-\mathbb{E}[U_t]=U_t-tSV-U_0\not=U_t-tSV$
